# Nodemanager and Resourcemanager not showing up in jps

Tags: linux, java, hadoop

I installed hadoop 2.9.2 and while running `start_all.sh` command there is no issue creeping up. But when I execute the jps command only 4 daemons show namely Namenode, Datanode, SecondaryNamenode, DataNode whilst the Resource and Node Manager aren't showing up. Can someone help me out?

```
Logs of execution:
hadoop@saran-HP-Notebook:~$ start-all.sh
This script is Deprecated. Instead use start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh
19/01/02 18:48:09 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /home/hadoop/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-namenode-saran-HP-Notebook.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /home/hadoop/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-saran-HP-Notebook.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /home/hadoop/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-secondarynamenode-saran-HP-Notebook.out
19/01/02 18:48:26 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
starting yarn daemons
starting resourcemanager, logging to /home/hadoop/hadoop/logs/yarn-hadoop-resourcemanager-saran-HP-Notebook.out
localhost: starting nodemanager, logging to /home/hadoop/hadoop/logs/yarn-hadoop-nodemanager-saran-HP-Notebook.out
hadoop@saran-HP-Notebook:~$ jps
20853 NameNode
21288 SecondaryNameNode
21050 DataNode
21771 Jps
```

Contents of log files:

```
/home/hadoop/hadoop/logs/yarn-hadoop-nodemanager-saran-HP-Notebook.out
ulimit -a for user hadoop
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 47281

/home/hadoop/hadoop/logs/yarn-hadoop-resourcemanager-saran-HP-Notebook.out
ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 47281
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 16384
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 47281
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: So what's in the logfiles? `/home/hadoop/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-namenode-saran-HP-Notebook.out` and `/home/hadoop/hadoop/logs/yarn-hadoop-resourcemanager-saran-HP-Notebook.out`?

Comment: Have you tried what is written in your question? `This script is Deprecated. Instead use start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh`

Comment: Yeah but that does yield the same results as above

Comment: did you fix the issue i ran in same problem

Comment: I ran into the same problem. Did you solve it?